# Can't uppercase variable bind to procedure in emacs racket r5rs?

Tags: emacs, racket

```
#lang r5rs

(define f (lambda (x y)
            (+ x y)))
(define G (lambda (x y)
            (+ x y)))
```

There is the code. When I run the racket REPL in Emacs and call G with 2 numbers, like `(G 1 2)`, it tells me that:

```
G: undefined;
  cannot reference an identifier before its definition
```

But `f` works well.

However if I set the module declaration to `#lang racket`, both `G` and `f` work. And in DrRacket, I pasted the same code above, both `G` and `f` work.

Is there anything about my emacs setting wrong?

Comment: What "Emacs setting"? I don't see what this question has to do with Emacs at all. Unclear.

Comment: @Drew This piece of code works in DrRacket, but not in emacs. That's why I think something wrong with my Emacs setting about racket.

Comment: So changing the first line makes it work from emacs?

Comment: @Sylwester Yes. I changed the first line to `#lang racket`, and it works. But I'm required to use r5rs.

Comment: For `#!r5rs` it's supposed to be insensitive by report so I guess emacs does something before racket sees it. `#!r6rs` is case sensitive so you should keep the R5RS code lowercased for future compatibility. Unless you really need to have upper case identifiers I would have worked around this by not writing upper case.